# Java link to view a specific email from the PST file in outlook

Tags: java, email, outlook

I have learned coding in JAVA for the sole purpose of creating a task manager where I can create tasks and keep all my files, phone calls and emails for the specific task in one place, or rather easily accessible from within the task. I have had success with all requirements but for the email. What I want to achieve is to have a "link" in my java program to a specific email in the PST file and when the link/button is clicked the email must be opened and viewed in Outlook.

I have tried Javamail and I can successfully access emails from the server - however I get too many emails per day and have to delete all emails from the server twice daily. The PST file seems like the best solution - it already has all the information I need without creating duplicates. 
I have tried libpst and I can access all of my emails in the PST file with success. However, I cannot seem to pick one email and have it open in Outlook. Since I will use this program only to make my job easier I would prefer not to have to buy any "connectors" and the like - I could just as well then buy a program like this and where is the fun in that?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look into using the [Outlook Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268893.aspx)? COM libraries can be accessed in Java using [Jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/). To open a message in Outlook by its entry id, use Application.Session.GetItemFromID.

Comment: I would seem that this is the answer to my problem, however I have been trying for more than a week now and i cannot get past getting the following error: Failed to create Ole Client. result = -2147221164

Comment: the error is REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG, which means the COM system cannot see in the registry the specified COM object's class name. Is Outlook installed? What is the bitness of your app and Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work since I havent used the libpst library. Can you export a single email message as a .eml or .msg file? If you can, then you can open the file using outlook easily enough.

This snippet should help

```
Desktop desktop=Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.open(<.eml/.msg file>);
```

Also, take a look the switches available to open outlook from the command prompt. 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/outlook-help/command-line-switches-HP001003110.aspx